# Error when reading Excel in R: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, r, excel

I am trying to read an `excel` file into `R`, the size is `14MB`, I got the error below:

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I know it has to do with memory but I have no programming background and don't know how to go about solving this issue :(

Comment: Here is the code I used to read the Excel file `Hire <- read.xlsx("Hires1.xlsx", 1)`

Comment: I installed the package `xlsx`, what is the other package?

Comment: installed openxlsx, still no luck, got the same error msg, I think it has something to do with memory leak? There are other similar posts re this error but not in R. But I cannot figure out how to fix it :(

Comment: You can use "openxlsx" package:                                                install.packages("openxlsx")                                                                      require(openxlsx)                                                                                                                     read.xlsx("....xlsx", sheet = 1, startRow = 1, colNames=TRUE)